# How make a mongo db query to find another collections id

Tags: mongodb

I have collections called name and address, and address _id are stored in name collection with a field addresses.

name collection document looks like below:

```
{fname: 'demon', addresses: [ObjectId('4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c'), ObjectId('4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c')]
```

Now, I'm trying to find documents with an address _id like below:

```
db.name.find({addresses: {$in: [ObjectId('4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c')]}}) // gives me null on the mongo shell.
```

Even worst is in javascript I just have `4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c` with me to make a search.

Comment: Works fine when I try it; but you can simplify that to `db.name.find({addresses: ObjectId('4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c')})`

Answer (score 0):

Deamon, it is working fine in my case. But you can also try these,these will also give you the same results.

```
db.name.find( { addresses: { $elemMatch: { $eq:ObjectId('4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c') } } });
```

Or

```
db.name.find({addresses: ObjectId('4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c')});
```

Comment: @Deamon - If my answer solved  your problem, please mark it as a correct answer to your question and close your question.